# Flutter Web SlectionArea with PageView, is it a bug or can i prevent this

Tags: flutter, dart

Demonstration video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4GQTJzoK633xwdE_wxmh3cXdywpFh9j/view?usp=sharing

Behavior: When you create a PageView inside a SelectionArea you can select a Text and scroll throw the PageView even the physics is never Scrollable. Sometimes I receive a random Exception which is not 100% reproducible:

```
globalRect.size.height >= _dragTargetRelatedToScrollOrigin.size.height
"Drag target size is larger than scrollable size, which may cause bouncing"
```

Try it yourself:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SelectionArea(child: PageViewBug()),
    );
  }
}

class PageViewBug extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageViewBug({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageViewBug> createState() => _PageViewBugState();
}

class _PageViewBugState extends State<PageViewBug> {
  final PageController controllerH = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PageViewBug')),
      body: PageView(controller: controllerH, physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//!!!!
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
        Center(
          child: Text("Page1"),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text("Page2"),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text("Page2"),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT 20 min later:
I have gained a few new insights:
If I move the SelectionArea in the WidgetTree further down, it "respects" the ScrollPhysics, but now it throws exceptions wildly as soon as I start to move the selected text out of the screen.

What I did:
**In my Main Project** Moved the Selection Area under my BlocBuilder, under my PageView, above every page widget:
E.g.:

```
-MaterialApp
--Scaffold
---BlocBuilder
----PageView
-----SelectionArea(Screen1)
-----SelectionArea(Screen2)
```

....
Then the exception is the same:

```
Error: Assertion failed: file:///D:/..../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable_helpers.dart:237:7
globalRect.size.width >= _dragTargetRelatedToScrollOrigin.size.width &&

        globalRect.size.height >= _dragTargetRelatedToScrollOrigin.size.height
"Drag target size is larger than scrollable size, which may cause bouncing"
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or if this is my fault. Maybe you can tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, and it's fine no errors are thrown, am using flutter 3.16.1 and i tested and it's working fine. I also add lorem text on page 1 still i can select the text with no error on the console, also i remove the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` still the page are scrolling fine and i can select the text inside with no errors or warning on the console.

Try this to solve the issue:

1. Either update your flutter sdk `if is not updated`
2. Try flutter clean then run the project again